# How to use javascript onkeydown on richfaces calendar?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, richfaces

I am using IE 8.
I want to start javascript function onkeydown in  component that clicks one input. Of course I tried do 
it like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function filtrOnEnter(formId,event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById(formId.toString()).click()
    }
}
```

```
<rich:calendar id="#{filterToDateId}" value="#{toDate}"
                                datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" enableManualInput="true"
                                inputStyle="width: 60px;" onkeydown="filtrOnEnter('#{filterActionId}',event)">
</rich:calendar>
```

This code works when used on regular input.
I also tried to start this filtrOnEnter() javascript function onkeydown on whole page. I did it like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     document.onkeydown = myEventHandler;

     function myEventHandler(e){
         filtrOnEnter('stringWithInputId',e);
     }
```

And it works nicely even for rich:calendar but only in firefox not ie8.
Do you have any suggestions how to resolve this problem in first or second way?
Thanks.

Comment: Teemu resolved this issue but due to curiosity I am also interested in javascript on rich:calendar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your argument name `event`. Older IEs have totally different event handling model. `window.event` is a global object containing all event properties. Now the argument shadows this global object. You can do something like this:

```
function filtrOnEnter(formId, evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
          ...
}
```

Comment: Actually this should work with `<rich:calendar...onkeydown="filtrOnEnter('#{filterActionId}',event)">`. `event` here refers to the global `event` object just like it should, no shadowing here.